# Cannot get correct lenght of an array pionter

Tags: c, hashtable, singly-linked-list, c-strings, strlen

Maybe this is something really stupid but I cannot find the way to solve it.

```
typedef struct Node{
    char *val;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

int main(){
    Node *table; // hashtable
    int n, i, j, choice, search;
    //int hash_num, val;

    char doc_name1[8] = "docA.txt";
    char doc_name2[8] = "docB.txt";
    char doc_name3[8] = "docC.txt";
    char doc_name4[8] = "docD.txt";

    // allocate table
    table = (Node*) malloc(N*sizeof(Node));     //Iniciando la table con N = 30 posiciones
    //make table "heads" NULL
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        table[i].next = NULL;
    }

    printf("--h(x) = xmod%d--\n",N);
    printf("\n\n");

    while(1){
        printf("1.Insertar registros\n");
        printf("2.Delete a number\n");
        printf("3.Search a number\n");
        printf("4.Show Hash Table\n");
        printf("0.Exit Programm\n");
        printf("\n--------\n");
        printf("Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice){
        case 0: return;
        case 1:
            table = insert(table, doc_name1);
            //table = insert(table, doc_name2);
            //table = insert(table, doc_name3);
            //table = insert(table, doc_name4);
            break;
        case 2:
            // delete a number
            printf("Give a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&search);
            table = del(table, N, search);
            printf("\n--------\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            // search for a number
            printf("Give a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&search);
            search_table(table, N, search);
            printf("\n--------\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            //print hashtable
            printf("-HASHTABLE-\n\n");
            print_table(table, N);
            printf("\n--------\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Node *insert(Node *table, char *val){
    Node *nn, *cur;
    int lenght = strlen(val);
    int hash_index = H(val);

    nn = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));   //Memoria para el nuevo nodo
    nn->val = malloc((lenght+1)*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(nn->val, val, lenght);    //Valor del nuevo nodo va a ser lo que pasamos
    nn->next = NULL;  //Siguiente apunta a null

    if(table[hash_index].next == NULL){ //Si donde apunta el indice a insertar no hay nada
        table[hash_index].next = nn;        //Insertamos ahí el nodo
        return table;                       //Devolvemos la tabla
    }
                                        //Si no
    cur = table[hash_index].next;       //cur recibe el siguiente
    while(cur->next != NULL){           //mientras que siga habiendo siguiente
        cur=cur->next;                  //seguimos avanzando
    }
    cur->next = nn;                     //Inserta al final de la lista enlazada
    return table;                       //Devuelve la tabla
}
```

That's not the complete code but I think is the necessary to show my problem.

The problem is that (using the CodeBlocks debugger) I can see how the variable **lenght** in the insert function initializes with value 8 at initial execution point. But when the function gets called and the reference to **doc_name** is passed, it changes to 11.
By the time writing this lines I noticed i t only showed 8 once, now it's always 11.

I can see it's somehow related to the fact that the argument **val** is being passed with some more characters than declared but how do I fix it?

Comment: `char doc_name1[8] = "docA.txt";` is wrong as strings in C need to be NUL terminated. So need 9 byte array for an 8 character string. Try `char doc_name1[] = "docA.txt";` That allows the compiler to work out the size of the array needed.

Comment: @kaylum, and since `doc_nameX` are never modified, they don't need to be copies of `"docX.txt"`. A pointer would be enough: `char *doc_nameX = "docX.txt";`. Or even better: `const char *doc_nameX = "docX.txt";`

Answer (score 1):

These character arrays

```
char doc_name1[8] = "docA.txt";
char doc_name2[8] = "docB.txt";
char doc_name3[8] = "docC.txt";
char doc_name4[8] = "docD.txt";
```

do not contain strings because they do not have enough space to accommodate zero terminating characters `'\0'` of the string literals used as initializers.

Thus using the function `strlen` with these array like in this declaration

```
int lenght = strlen(val);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead write

```
char doc_name1[] = "docA.txt";
char doc_name2[] = "docB.txt";
char doc_name3[] = "docC.txt";
char doc_name4[] = "docD.txt";
```

Another problem with strings is that in these statements

```
nn->val = malloc((lenght+1)*sizeof(char));
strncpy(nn->val, val, lenght);
```

again the zero terminating character `'\0'` is not copied. You need to write

```
nn->val = malloc((lenght+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy( nn->val, val );
```

At least the second parameter of the function `insert` should have the qualifier `const`

```
Node *insert(Node *table, const char *val);
```

because a passed string is not changed within the function.